# Search recipes by name on Gojee

Tags: gojee

I know the name of a particular drink I want (Strawberry Wallbanger)  and would like to see if Gojee has the recipe for it. Is this possible?

Comment: Site appears to be dead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way is to search by ingredients. Insert the respective ingredient(s) into the **I Crave** field and it will give you a list of drinks related to it/them.

[image]

The only "Wallbanger" they have is *Harvey Wallbanger*.